# systemd (OnFailure) using ssmtp with gmail can't send mail

Tags: linux, systemd, ssmtp, gmail

Some important service:

```
[Unit]
...
OnFailure=status-email@%n.service
```

`status-email@.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=status email for %i to user

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/systemd-email.sh <recipient> %i
User=root
Group=systemd-journal

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I'm getting error `systemd-email.sh[117310]: ssmtp: Cannot open smtp.gmail.com:587`

I can send mail manually `./systemd-email.sh $RECIPIENT $SERVICE_NAME`

It's also working as cronjob.

My `/etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf`:

```
root=<gmail address>
mailhub=smtp.gmail.com:465
FromLineOverride=YES
AuthUser=<gmail address>
AuthPass=<password>
UseTLS=YES
```

Why cron can send mail in this setup but systemd cannot?

Comment: You posted two items: `systemd-email.sh[117310]: ssmtp: Cannot open smtp.gmail.com:587` and later, `mailhub=smtp.gmail.com:465`. Something is mis-configured in the first case to use port 587 instead of the correct port 465.

Comment: That's right, I found the problem. In `/etc/ssmtp/revaliases` I left wrong ports... `root:username@gmail.com:smtp.gmail.com:587
mainuser:username@gmail.com:smtp.gmail.com:587`. Changed them to 465 and it's all working now.

Answer (score 0):

Per the comments, the problem was an incorrectly configured port number somewhere else. Please consider deleting this question, as the main thing it brings to the community and the site/network is "Why you should do a detailed search/research, troubleshooting, and/or diagnostics to exhaust all avenues of resolving the issue on your own."

The only thing I would add to help other/future users is application of various template files and configuration files (setting an environment variable to the correct value, then using it in other files) to ensure a single change propagates to all sub-ordinate configuration files.